# LOESS model from msir package. SDs approaching zero

Tags: regression, non-linear-regression, loess

I am using loess.sd function from msir package.  For some reason, the SDs generated are approaching zero in my test data set.

When I plotted it, the prediction intervals essentially converges... as you can see in the plot [test plot using msir generated parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0tt1.jpg)

x = date and year
y = some value that we are trending overtime

`plot(test_data, main = "test data", col = "purple", pch = 2)`
`lines(test_data2$x, test_data2$y)`
`lines(test_data2$x, test_data2$upper, lty = 2)`
`lines(test_data2$x, test_data2$lower, lty = 2)`

Thanks in advance for your input!